# How to put a word that varies in length at the beginning of a <textarea>?

Tags: html, css

I have a `<textarea>` that needs to have a word at the beginning, ie.: **Message:**
So, I applied `text-indent` to this.

The problem is that this text has a number in the end, so it can vary in lenght, ie.. **Message 2:** or **Message 76:**.

Example:

```css
.container {
  font-size: 15px;
  position: relative;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
textarea {
  border-radius: 8px;
  font-size: 15px;
  resize: none;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  height: 150px;
  width: 220px;
  text-indent: 86px;
  padding: 12px 16px;
}
span {
  left: 17px;
  top: 13px;
  font-weight: 600;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <textarea name="" id="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Id asperiores voluptatibus quidem quasi est, dolorum similique dolor facere ut recusandae! Eaque, quas! Atque officia doloremque odio distinctio deleniti commodi debitis.
  </textarea>
  <span>Message 4:</span>
</div>
```

How can I put a text at the beginning so that, when it has a longer length, it doesn't invade the `<textarea>` text?

I am trying to achieve this using only CSS.
Maybe there is a different way instead of using indentation, but I still haven't figured out. Also because the absolutely positioned element is fixed there.

Comment: Use a regular div with `contenteditable="true"` and style it per your desire, of course put the span tag inside it.

Comment: I had considered it as well, but I would have to change a lot of things. Anyway, I think this will be the solution. Thank you.

Comment: Np, I think this is the easiest way, also pretty elegant solution.